# Hide attributes from model on query load

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to generate a query that returns a list of flight requests along with the user who requested them but I'm trying to omit the `email` attribute from the user, I know I can add `email` to the hidden array in the `User` model but I only want to hide it from this one query so it would not make sense to have to add the `makeVisible` method to every other query I'm running on my app.

The query I've got is this:

```
FlightRequest::get()
->where('public', 1)
->whereNull('acceptee_id')
->sortBy('id')
->load('aircraft', 'requestee');
```

I've tried adding `->makeHidden('requestee.email')` to the end of the query but that doesnt work

Comment: This is very poorly optimized... Your initial query should be `FlightRequest::with(['aircraft', 'requestee'])->where('public', 1)->whereNull('acceptee_id')->orderBy('id')->get()`. When you call `::get()`, you're loading every record from the DB into memory, then performing a bunch of additional filtering/sorting/loading, which is incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by specifying the requestee 'columns' manually, `->load('aircraft', 'requestee:id,username,name')`

Comment: why are you not having the database do all the filtering and sorting instead of getting all the records then filtering them? and you can use `with` to eager load those relationships